# Split string on certain words case insensitive using regex (alteryx)

Tags: regex, alteryx

If my string is:

```
mary lamb The beast the castle THE large lake
```

I want to produce:

```
mary lamb
The beast
the castle
The large lake
```

If I do `(?i)(?:(.*the))` then it only splits on the last the but i want to split on each "the" regardless of case.

Comment: can lazy the * and add a + `(?i)(?:(.*?the)+)`

Comment: @skara9 - That ignores the first "the" and splits after "the" for the others

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
(?i)(?=\bthe\b)
(?i)\s+(?=\bthe\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uApRsx/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\bthe\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `the` as a whole word.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: Problem is, this is invalid in Alteryx as it complains of an empty expression if i try to parse it. If I tokenize it, the fields are empty. Works in your example mind!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to RegEx:

1. Do a formula to replace `"the"` with `CHR(13)+"the"`
2. Do a simpler Text to Columns, with `\n` for the delimiter and splitting to rows.